# Google Sheets/Script: How do I compare two dates and then tick a checkbox based on the result?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Have a spreadsheet (named) where I have a column of dates (B2) and a column of checkboxes (C2). I need to compare B2 to Today() if the date is older than X number of years then C2 needs to be ticked (TRUE); else do nothing.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_FdOgb0RKqxu6mIggmR2n5JDitpPjxzs1h-fn6bGnHs/edit?usp=sharing

Attempted possible formula's but this seems to be a script function. Attempted a few scripts but no luck.

Update: Code from Ramón below.

```
function dates(){
   const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Testing');
   const initialDate=new Date(ss.getRange('I1').getValue()).getTime();
   const dates=ss.getRange('D2:D23').getValues();
   let results=[]
   dates.forEach((date,index)=>{
     let newDate=new Date(date).getTime();
     let difference=(initialDate-newDate)/1000/3600/24/365;
     //gets the value of the checkbox
     let checkbox= ss.getRange(index+4,6).getValue();
 
     //evaluates if the difference between years is greater than 2 OR if the checkbox is already checked
     difference>=2 || checkbox ? results.push([true]) : results.push([false])
   })
 ss.getRange('F2:F23').setValues(results);
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Google Sheet function that calculates the number of years between two dates and accepts and optional argument depending on how you count the years (it seems a financial counting).

[YEARFRAC](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092989?hl=en)

The formula in C2 would be:

`=arrayformula(if(YEARFRAC(A2,B2:B18,1)>=2,TRUE()))`

where you can change the number of years (I wrote "2") but you can reference it to another cell depending if you want to change the number of years.

If you desire to use a script, it could be something like the following (I add the condition to leave the checkbox checked if it's already checked. Condition that was not stated in the question):

```
function dates(){
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Copy of B');
  const initialDate=new Date(ss.getRange('A2').getValue()).getTime();
  const dates=ss.getRange('B2:B18').getValues();
  let results=[]
  dates.forEach((date,index)=>{
    let newDate=new Date(date).getTime();
    let difference=(initialDate-newDate)/1000/3600/24/365;
    //gets the value of the checkbox
    let checkbox= ss.getRange(index+2,3).getValue();

    //evaluates if the difference between years is greater than 2 OR if the checkbox is already checked
    difference>=2 || checkbox ? results.push([true]) : results.push([false])
  })
ss.getRange('C2:C18').setValues(results);
}
```

[.getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime)

Comment: So I already have a function for another cell (different sheet) that is 

=DATEDIF(D2,$I$1,"Y")>=2

Which works but doesn't allow me to change the state of the checkbox in another cell obviously.

Comment: Sorry but I don't completely understand your goal maybe because I don't see your original sheet. So I assume you have in another sheet already a column with the results for every date, let's say you have in column A in sheet "different sheet" values with true, false, false, true, and so on. You can still copy those values in C2 with the formula ={'different sheet'!A1:A17}

Comment: The Original sheet is nothing different than the example sheet made above.

I need to be able to evaluate the difference between cells in column B with today()'s date (A1). If that date is more than 2 years in the past then the corresponding checkbox in column (example: C2 next to B2 cell ) date needs to be TRUE. If the date in any cell in B is less than 2 years the corresponding checkbox in column C remains FALSE

Comment: I edited the answer, adding a script. But I still don't see why the previous formula in my answer doesn't work in your situation. I apologize for my english :)

Comment: No worries. The script does work for exactly what I am looking for minus 2 issues which is if checkbox already ticked, keep it ticked but also need to be able to manually tick off the boxes

Comment: I edited the answer again. You can always tick off/on checkboxes manually. If you think it's a correct answer, mark it as so, so that other users might find the answer helpful.

Comment: Hey Ramón appreciate the help. I've updated the sheet template and run the script works well. Came across one bug where if the script is run repeatedly the checkbox at the bottom ends up moving up. I added the code block to my original post

Answer (score 0):

You can put your DATEDIF(...)>=2 function directly in a checkbox cell (just overwriting its default FALSE that appears in the formula bar), and it will generate a checkmark if it evaluates to TRUE. Note that the checkbox won't be manually controllable any more (if you click on it, its state will not change).

Comment: That's part of the problem, I need to be able to manually check off the boxes if needed

Comment: Oh OK, I see. There are some hacky approaches that would allow you to manually override the status of checkboxes which were not checked as a result of the DATEDIF formula (i.e. to check unchecked boxes), but there's no formula-based approach that would allow you to do the inverse (i.e. to uncheck formula-driven checked boxes)